# Add koa plugin to eggjs framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

I would like to add [koa-validate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-validate) to [eggjs](https://eggjs.org/).

Code from koa-validate [readme](https://github.com/RocksonZeta/koa-validate/blob/master/README.md):

```
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();
var router = require('koa-router')();
require('koa-validate')(app);

app.use(require('koa-body')({multipart:true , formidable:{keepExtensions:true}}));
app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods());
```

So I tried to add it as middleware as described in the [eggjs docs](https://github.com/eggjs/egg/blob/master/docs/source/en/intro/egg-and-koa.md):

```
// app/middleware/validate.js

const validate = require('koa-validate');

module.exports = (options, app) => {
    validate(app);
    return function session(ctx, next) {
        return next();
    }
}
```

But what I am actually looking for is to **load the plugin 'on boot'** and have the app object to add the validate plugin. Do you have any idea where I should place this?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I solved it myself:

Add **/app.js** for life-cycle hooks and add the following code:

```
const validate = require('koa-validate');
class AppBootHook {
    constructor(app) {
        this.app = app;
        validate(app);
    }
}
module.exports = AppBootHook;
```

Instead of the documented this.checkQuery() the function is available as this.**ctx**.checkQuery.

Maybe this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer but for egg js validating, there is already an official plugin there: https://github.com/eggjs/egg-validate

For the real answer: You can refer the example repo: https://github.com/Jeff-Tian/egg-useragent. This is a real world example that adds koa-useragent to eggjs framework. Core code is:

```js
import {Application} from "egg"

import koaUserAgent from 'koa-useragent'

export default (app: Application) => {
    app.use(koaUserAgent)
};
```